# TypeScript doesn't found enum in array

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I have an enum like that:

```js
export enum Roles {
   ADMIN, NONE;
}
```

I get an object which use this enum. The object:

```js
export interface User {
   name: string;
   roles: Roles[];
}
```

I get it with a web request and json. After receiving the web request, I log the object which is well filled:

```js
{ name: 'Admin', roles: Array(1) }
```

The role array is:

```js
roles: ['ADMIN']
```

So, I try to check if the user as the admin role like that:

```js
user.roles.includes(Roles.ADMIN);
```

But it always return false. I also tried `user.roles.indexOf(Roles.ADMIN) != -1` but it's the same result.

After some search, I see multiple post talking about `Object.values()`. I tried to print with this method, or use `includes`, but I get the same result.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enum` entries in TypeScript default [Numeric Enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums) that start at `0` and auto-increment.

If you are working with an API or other data source that uses string representations, you need to implement your enum as a [String Enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums)

> While string enums don’t have auto-incrementing behavior, string enums have the benefit that they “serialize” well. In other words, if you were debugging and had to read the runtime value of a numeric enum, the value is often opaque - it doesn’t convey any useful meaning on its own (though reverse mapping can often help). String enums allow you to give a meaningful and readable value when your code runs, independent of the name of the enum member itself.

So for your code, you would do this:

```
export enum Roles {
  ADMIN = 'ADMIN',
  NONE = 'NONE';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Enums in typescript by default have numeric values, so you in your case `'ADMIN' = 0`, therefore `user.roles.includes(Roles.ADMIN);` will never return true. One option is to set your Enums to string values something like this

```
export enum Roles {
  ADMIN = 'ADMIN', 
  NONE = 'NONE'
}
```

Then using `user.roles.includes(Roles.ADMIN);` should return true